# Using Netlify lambda functions to send emails from a GatsbyJS site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-lambda, gatsby, netlify

I am following this tutorial https://dev.to/char_bone/using-netlify-lambda-functions-to-send-emails-from-a-gatsbyjs-site-3pnb I have everything set up but I get the following error in my terminal. I am able to get the hello world app working for the lambda function from here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-12-17-turning-the-static-dynamic/ which is a prerequisite to start the first tutorial.

`RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined`

Here is the code with the form on it. And you can also see the whole repo below.

```
import React from 'react'
import { HelmetDatoCms } from 'gatsby-source-datocms'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default ({ data }) => {

  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
  })

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 }

 const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("test");

  try{
    const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/sendmail", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(formState),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log(response);
      return
    }

    console.log("success email");

  } catch(e){

    console.log("error");

  }
}

  return(

  <Layout>

    <article className="sheet">
      <HelmetDatoCms seo={data.datoCmsPricing.seoMetaTags} />

        <section className="left-package-details">

          tests

        <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <label>
          Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={formState.name}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Email
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formState.email}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Subject
          <input
            type="textarea"
            name="subject"
            value={formState.subject}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          message
          <input
            type="text"
            name="message"
            value={formState.message}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>


  )
}
```

**Update**

Now Based on Pierre's answer I am getting the 500 error

```
Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: POST /sendmail 
Response with status 500 in 3 ms.
```

I wonder if it has to do with it POST'ing from localhost, at least I know it's sendgrid giving me the error now.

I looked at the npm debugging section and saw this code, not sure exactly where to put it?

```
const {
  classes: {
    Mail,
  },
} = require('@sendgrid/helpers');
const mail = Mail.create(data);
const body = mail.toJSON();
console.log(body);
```

console error

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8000/.netlify/functions/sendmail", redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8000/.netlify/functions/sendmail"
redirected: false
status: 500
ok: false
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

**Second Update**

I get the following error in terminal now *Actually I don't think I even need a cc, I think it is saying I don't have a to value, so maybe my env varaiable SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL is not being passed?*

```
Provide at least one of to, cc or bcc
```

Now if I add a cc like this

```
const msg = {
        to: SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL,
        cc:"email@email.com",
        from: email,
        subject: subject ? subject : 'Contact Form Submission',
        html: body,
    };
```

Then I get a `Unauthorized` message

For my environment variables there is a .env file at my root that contains the following

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.longsting
SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL=myemail@email.com
```

This is the line that is supposed to grab the env variables

```
const { SENDGRID_API_KEY, SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL } = process.env
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it yourself? Please do, if not, and add your findings to the post, along with any guesses.

Comment: I am totally open to doing so, how would I go about debugging it? I've tried everything I could think of on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [your source code](https://github.com/wispyco/riel-design/blob/master/src/lambda/sendmail.js), I'm pretty sure that the sendgrid `send` function raises an exception, and that you don't handle it properly:

```js
try{
    await sgMail.send(msg)

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "Message sent"
    }
} catch(e){
    return {
        statusCode: e.code, // e.code is probably undefined
        body: e.message
    }
}
```

I took a quick look at the sendgrid SDK, and I see nothing suggesting that it throws errors with a `code` property corresponding to a valid http status code.

The consequence is that you return a response with `undefined` as status code, hence the `ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE` error.

Try replacing your `catch` block by the following, and you should at least get a proper response and hopefully, a useful error message from the sendgrid SDK:

```js
try {
    // same as before
} catch(e){
    return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: e.message
    }
}
```

### Update

Your issue might be with your environment variables. You should make sure that `SENDGRID_API_KEY` and `SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL` are set properly.

For your development environment, I think you need to add `require('dotenv').config()` in your function file.

For your production environment (Netlify), you should set the variables in the UI: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#declare-variables

Comment: Ok, I get a 500 error now, so it shows that sendgrid SDK is giving me an error, now it's POST from localhost because I am on dev, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I added more debugging information in my question above, hopefully it helps. I looked at the debugging side of the npm package. and used  `@sendgrid/helpers`

Comment: It wasn't the sengrid helper that was giving me the console error it was from your status code, so I don't know any more info beyond the console message I added above

Comment: Could you do `console.log(e.message)` in the catch block?

Comment: I added the message and what I tried after above, in the update two section

Comment: Probably an issue with your environment variables, see my updated answer

Comment: I thought that might be the case as well, I posted what my .env file at my root looks like, beyond putting in the api key. Not sure what else to do. Maybe try and hard code them and see if it works then

Comment: Hard coding them worked. What might I be doing wrong with my .env file?

Comment: Got it, the file needed this `require('dotenv').config();` Could you put that in your answer for others. I'll give ya the bounty when it lets me.

Comment: I was about to say that! I also added the instructions for the prod (Netlify) environment

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've dropped into similar problem and below I'm attaching my solution to your problem.

#### folder structure - piece

```
Project
 |
 +-- public   
 +-- src
 |  |  
 |  +-- functions
 |      |
 |      +-- sendmail.js
 |
 |  +-- components
 |      |
 |      +-- ContactForm.js
 |
```

#### Lambda functions folder in root directory

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")
const { SENDGRID_API_KEY, SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL } = process.env

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const { email, message, name } = payload

  sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

  const msg = {
    to: SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL,
    from: email,
    subject: `New message from ${name}`,
    text: message,
  }

  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg)
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Message sent",
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.code,
      body: err.message,
    }
  }
}
```

#### Contact form - piece

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { name: "", email: "", message: "" },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, { resetForm, setSubmitting }) => {
      axios
        .post("/.netlify/functions/sendmail", values)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          setSubmitting(false)
          resetForm({})
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          setSubmitting(false)
        })
    },
  })
```

#### package.json - packages needed for lambda functions

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.5.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.3",
    "netlify-lambda": "^1.6.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
},
"scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "run-p start:**",
    "start:app": "npm run develop",
    "start:lambda": "netlify-lambda serve src/functions",
    "build": "gatsby build && netlify-lambda build src/functions",
    "build:app": "gatsby build",
    "build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/functions"
 }
```

#### netlify.toml

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  functions = "functions"
  publish = "public"
```

#### gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // other setup

  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/.netlify/functions/",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:9000",
        pathRewrite: {
          "/.netlify/functions/": "",
        },
      })
    )
  },
}
```

Set proper **env** variables on Netlify and you should be good to go. Hopefully it helps someone.